# Vagrant add box error, said cannot create XXX, .vagrant.d\\tmp, bsdtar.EXE: Error

Tags: windows, vagrant

I'm using Windows 10, and I installed the  version of Vagrant 1.8.1.

I type my command:

```
vagrant box add oog-dev resources/ubuntu-16.04.4-server-amd64.iso
```

It always give my error

> x dists/unstable: Can't create '\\?\C:\Users\Administrator\.vagrant.d\tmp\vagrant-box-add-temp-20180719-11832-1n504qm\dists\unstable'
>   x install/hwe-netboot/ldlinux.c32: Can't create '\\?\C:\Users\Administrator\.vagrant.d\tmp\vagrant-box-add-temp-20180719-11832-1n504qm\install\hwe-netboot\ldlinux.c32'
>   x isolinux/hi.hlp
>   x install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/pxelinux.cfg/default: Can't create '\\?\C:\Users\Administrator\.vagrant.d\tmp\vagrant-box-add-temp-20180719-11832-1n504qm\install\netboot\ubuntu-installer\amd64\pxelinux.cfg\default'
>   x install/hwe-netboot/pxelinux.cfg: Can't create '\\?\C:\Users\Administrator\.vagrant.d\tmp\vagrant-box-add-temp-20180719-11832-1n504qm\install\hwe-netboot\pxelinux.cfg'
>   x ubuntu: Can't create '\\?\C:\Users\Administrator\.vagrant.d\tmp\vagrant-box-add-temp-20180719-11832-1n504qm\ubuntu'
>   x install/netboot/pxelinux.0: Can't create '\\?\C:\Users\Administrator\.vagrant.d\tmp\vagrant-box-add-temp-20180719-11832-1n504qm\install\netboot\pxelinux.0'
>   x .disk/base_installable
>   x install/netboot/pxelinux.cfg: Can't create '\\?\C:\Users\Administrator\.vagrant.d\tmp\vagrant-box-add-temp-20180719-11832-1n504qm\install\netboot\pxelinux.cfg'
>   x dists/stable: Can't create '\\?\C:\Users\Administrator\.vagrant.d\tmp\vagrant-box-add-temp-20180719-11832-1n504qm\dists\stable'
>   x install/hwe-netboot/pxelinux.0: Can't create '\\?\C:\Users\Administrator\.vagrant.d\tmp\vagrant-box-add-temp-20180719-11832-1n504qm\install\hwe-netboot\pxelinux.0'
>   x install/netboot/ldlinux.c32: Can't create '\\?\C:\Users\Administrator\.vagrant.d\tmp\vagrant-box-add-temp-20180719-11832-1n504qm\install\netboot\ldlinux.c32'
>   x install/hwe-netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/pxelinux.cfg/default: Can't create '\\?\C:\Users\Administrator\.vagrant.d\tmp\vagrant-box-add-temp-20180719-11832-1n504qm\install\hwe-netboot\ubuntu-installer\amd64\pxelinux.cfg\default'
>   bsdtar.EXE: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly found the solution.

It because the `vagrant add` need using xxx.box file instead of xxx.iso file. The box file can be downloaded from https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search?order=desc&page=1&provider=virtualbox&q=ubuntu&sort=downloads&utf8=%E2%9C%93.